# Rewriting Zend Framework 1 App with Zend Framework 2

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, bootstrapping

In my ZF1 app I have plugin, which is loaded at `Bootstrap.php` and check whether my app is installed. If my app is not installed then it redirects the user to an install module.

My question is now in ZF2 how can I do this?

Comment: Register a module, listen to the Bootstrap event, redirect the response when condition is met. If you want detailed answers, ask detailed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ZF2 has a bootstrap event [and you can read all about it in the documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.module-manager.module-class.html#the-mvc-bootstrap-event).

So the answer is: yes you can do this.